# Are privileges lost if reputations fall (below threshold) because of awarding bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, privileges

Since privileges are obtained after crossing respective thresholds, I was wondering do they also get taken away if reputations fall back, especially after awarding bounty, to a level below the threshold.

Comment: If you have a question which applies across the network the answer can often be found somewhere on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you'll lose privileges. See the [Help Center article about setting bounties](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> - If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.

Comment: It may seem unfair that having earned the respect of a community you may lose privileges by offering a bounty. But it seems to be a general rule that thresholds work this way.